# Render html to excel using php excel

Tags: php, html, phpexcel

I am trying to render html into excel using php excel. Here is my code.

```
    $value = "<ul><li>new</li></ul>";
    $objTpl = new PHPExcel();
    $objTpl->createSheet(0)
    ->setTitle("Title")
    ->setCellValue ( 'A1', 'Value' );
    $objTpl->getSheet(0)->setCellValueExplicit("A2", $value);

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; ');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Test"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objTpl, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

PHP excel is creating the excel but the cell value is coming up as

```
<ul><li>new</li></ul>
```

But i want it to be shown as

- new

.

Is there is way to do that in php. Please help!

Comment: Looks like `PHPExcel` has been deprecated and PHPSpreadSheet is now recommended: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Comment: How is the data you are working with formatted? I assume you want to take an unordered list and put each item in a row, but how does the rest of the data look. Is there more than one column?